# DirectX11 Camera Movement

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx-11

So I was programming some movement on a car I have in my program here.

Do I just increase the `Z position` of the camera on `XMVECTOR pos`? I did this earlier and it went forward and all but started to turn the camera towards the ground.

`XMVECTOR pos = XMVectorSet(x, y, z + mCarTranslation.z, 1.0f);`

Anyways here's part of my code.

```
/ Convert Spherical to Cartesian coordinates.
float x = mRadius*sinf(mPhi)*cosf(mTheta);
float z = mRadius*sinf(mPhi)*sinf(mTheta);
float y = mRadius*cosf(mPhi);

mEyePosW = XMFLOAT3(x, y, z);

// Build the view matrix.
XMVECTOR pos    = XMVectorSet(x, y, z, 1.0f);
XMVECTOR target = XMVectorZero();
XMVECTOR up     = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

XMMATRIX V = XMMatrixLookAtLH(pos, target, up);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&mView, V);

// Button down event.
if (GetAsyncKeyState('W') & 0x8000)
{
    mCarTranslation.z += -4.0f*dt;
}
if(GetAsyncKeyState('S') & 0x8000)
{
    mCarTranslation.z += 2.0f*dt;
}
if(GetAsyncKeyState('A') & 0x8000)
{
    mCarTranslation.x += 1.0f*dt;
}
if(GetAsyncKeyState('D') & 0x8000)
{
    mCarTranslation.x += -1.0f*dt;
}

XMMATRIX carScale = XMMatrixScaling(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
XMMATRIX carOffset = XMMatrixTranslation(mCarTranslation.x, mCarTranslation.y, mCarTranslation.z);
XMStoreFloat4x4(&mCarWorld, XMMatrixMultiply(carScale, carOffset));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera ends up rotating towards the ground because you're recreating the matrix every frame with the same target position (0,0,0).  If you want to maintain the same orientation, you need to set the target position to be relative to the eye position, i.e. `target = XMVectorSet(x - xInitial, y - yInitial, z - zInitial, 1.0f)`.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me considering intial was just 0? `XMVECTOR pos = XMVectorSet(x + mCarTranslation.x, y + mCarTranslation.y, z + mCarTranslation.z, 1.0f);
 XMVECTOR target = XMVectorSet(mCarTranslation.x, mCarTranslation.y, mCarTranslation.z, 1.0f);`